# Setting up a background image for my menu and being resizable

Tags: java, swing, menu

So i am trying to make a Menu for a game i am working on.

I want to put an image as background at my `menuPanel` but i cant figure out how to let the image rescale every time i am raising the window. I have made a `JLabel` and i have imported an image from my main method and when i launch the game i can see that the image is correctly imported but i want to fill up all `menuPanel` and also stretch as i am raising the window to full screen or decreasing to the Minimum size of my frame.
How can i do that?

[image]

As you can see at the screenshot i want the text to be on top of the image and the image as a background and full screen.

```
public class Window extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6331412385749386309L;
    
    private static final int WIDTH = 1024, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private JFrame frame;
    
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel menuPanel;
    private JPanel buttonsPanel;
    private JPanel playPanel;
    private JPanel optionsPanel;
    
    private JButton playBtn;
    private JButton optionsBtn;
    private JButton quitBtn;
    
    private int currWidth = WIDTH, currHeight = HEIGHT;

    public Window(String title, Game game) {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        
        frame.setSize(1024, 576);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        
        frame.requestFocus();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        menu();
        game.start();
    }
    
    private void menu() {
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
        
        // menuPanel config
        menuPanel = new JPanel();
        menuPanel.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        menuPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        mainPanel.add(menuPanel, "menuPanel");
        
        buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setBorder(null);
        buttonsPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        
            // playBtn config
        playBtn = new JButton("Play");
        playBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        playBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD, 40));
        playBtn.setOpaque(false);
        playBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        playBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        playBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        
            // optionsBtn config
        optionsBtn = new JButton("Options");
        optionsBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        optionsBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD, 35));
        optionsBtn.setOpaque(false);
        optionsBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        optionsBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        optionsBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        
            //quitBtn config
        quitBtn = new JButton("Quit");
        quitBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        quitBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD, 35));
        quitBtn.setOpaque(false);
        quitBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        quitBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        quitBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        
        GroupLayout gl_buttonsPanel = new GroupLayout(buttonsPanel);
        gl_buttonsPanel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_buttonsPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(gl_buttonsPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(gl_buttonsPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(quitBtn, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 175, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(playBtn, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 175, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(optionsBtn, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        gl_buttonsPanel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_buttonsPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_buttonsPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(playBtn)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(optionsBtn, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(quitBtn, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(gl_buttonsPanel);
        
        //
        JLabel menuImageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Game.menu_image.getScaledInstance(700, 400, Image.SCALE_FAST)));
        //
        
        GroupLayout gl_menuPanel = new GroupLayout(menuPanel);
        gl_menuPanel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_menuPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(gl_menuPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(menuImageLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 762, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0)
                    .addComponent(buttonsPanel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 195, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_menuPanel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_menuPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_menuPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(161)
                    .addComponent(buttonsPanel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(124))
                .addComponent(menuImageLabel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 537, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        menuPanel.setLayout(gl_menuPanel);
        
        // playPanel config
        playPanel = new JPanel();
        playPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 255));
        mainPanel.add(playPanel, "playPanel");
        
        // optionsPanel config
        optionsPanel = new JPanel();
        optionsPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        mainPanel.add(optionsPanel, "optionsPanel");
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        setActions();
    }
    
    private void setActions() {
        
        // playBtn action
        playBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                playBtn.setForeground(new Color(200, 210, 10));
            }
            
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                playBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            }
            
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                menuPanel.setVisible(false);
                playPanel.setVisible(true);
                optionsPanel.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        
        // optionsBtn action
        optionsBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                optionsBtn.setForeground(new Color(200, 210, 10));
            }
            
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                optionsBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            }
            
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                menuPanel.setVisible(false);
                playPanel.setVisible(false);
                optionsPanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        // quitBtn action
        quitBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                quitBtn.setForeground(new Color(200, 210, 10));
            }
            
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                quitBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            }
            
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void tick() {
        mainPanel.getSize(new Dimension(currWidth, currHeight));
        
        System.out.println(currWidth + ", " + currHeight);
    }
    
    public void render() {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is based on parent/child relationships.

So if you want the button displayed on the background the structure of your code needs to be:

```
- frame
    - background component
        - buttons panel
```

The easiest way to do this is to use a `JLabel` with your image as the background. Then you add the buttons panel to the label. The only issue is that by default a `JLabel` doesn't use a layout manager so you need to see the layout manager to achieve your desired effect.

I would suggest using a `GridBagLayout`, then the buttons will be centered on the panel. The basic code would be:

```
JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
buttons.add(...);

JLabel background = new JLabel(...);
background.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
background.add(buttons, new GridBagConstraints());
```

The label will be displayed at the size of the background image.

If you want the background image to scale as the frame size changes, then you have a couple of options:

1. Use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). It will automatically scale the image to the space available.
2. Replace the JLabel with a JPanel and paint the image yourself. Check out the [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) which can be configured to automatically scale an image.

Edit:

> i tried reading the code and its really confusing.

Well, the intent was not for you to read the code. The intent was for you to use the code.

When you program you learn how to use classes and the methods of the class. When you use the `ImageIcon` class did you read the code first or just learn how to use its contructor?

Now I agree, the two classes don't have a published API but you really only need to understand the constructors and methods of the classes in order to use them.

If you read the `Stretch Icon` blog it states:

*StretchIcon is a drop-in replacement for ImageIcon, which it extends, except that ImageIcon’s no-arg constructor isn’t supported.*

So that means that if you would normally use:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("background.jpg") );
```

you would use the following for the `StretchIcon`:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel( new StretchIcon("background.jpg") );
```

Similarly for the `BackgroundPanel`, if you read the blog it states that it is:

*an extension of JPanel that provides some custom painting support for the drawing of images*

It then goes on to say that the default is to paint the image "scaled" which is what you want. So all you need to figure out is which constuctor to use to create the panel.

For a regular panel you would use:

```
JPanel background = new JPanel();
```

For the `BackgroundPanel` the simplest constructor to use would be the first constructor of the class which simply takes an `Image` as a parameter:

```
JPanel background = new BackgroundPanel(image);
```

Now you have a panel and you simply add your 3 buttons to the panel.

I did not write the `StretchIcon` class so I don't know the details of the code, and I don't care about the details as long as the class does what I expect it to do.

I did write the `BackgroundPanel` class so if you has specific questions then I can probably help you. But I don't have time to guess which part of the code you find confusing.

Edit 2:

> I have 3 buttons and i want them to be at the cemter and stretch too so they stay at the center of the image

This is about learning how to use layout managers. I never use an IDE to generate my code. I want full control over the code. This allows your code to be cleaner an more easily maintained.

This allows you to choose the appropriate layout manager for the job and allows you to easily nest panels with different layout mangers. In this case you want to use the GridBagLayout which by default will center horizontally and vertically any component added to it.

By default the `BackgroundPanel` uses a BorderLayout. But you can easily change it to use the GridBagLayout. Then I would use a second panel with a GridLayout for the buttons.

So the code would be something like:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 0) );
buttonPanel.add(playBtn);
...

backgroundPanel.add(buttonPanel, new GridBagConstraints());
```

Now as the frame size is changed the buttons will automatically re-center.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

Keep a link to the Swing tutorial handy. It contains information and example of most Swing basics.

Comment: Look dude seriously i wanna understand the answer you gave me... Because as you said its a more tidy solution and i want to implement it to my code. Look when i made the topic i had already been coding for 18 hours straight and so i picked the other answer bause it felt easier and i didnt had the courage to go search and be focus to understand the StretchIcon and BackgroundPanel. I am sorry for what i said before. Can you explain a little bit how those two things work because i tried reading the code and its really confusing. Again thanks for your help and your time to put out this answer!

Comment: Alright i saw your edit and i understood it perfectly so thanks for your edit amd your time. I wanna though something different with buttons... I have 3 buttons and i want them to be at the cemter and stretch too so they stay at the center of the image. I tried using GroupLayout on the buttonsPanel but the anchors where not working be cause i was picking the anchor hooking to both sides and still the buttons ended up stay at the top of the center of the first window when i was putting it on full screen. Any better idea of how to make them be at center all the time and stretch with the window?

Comment: Oh and also a mistake on your code was at the last box its `Jpanel background = new BackgroundPanel(image);` instead of JPanel.

Comment: @Kamora,  *Any better idea of how to make them be at center all the time and stretch with the  window?* - see edit 2.

Comment: alright i made it and it works perfectly. One more question that i have is that after this tweak the `buttonsPanel` takes up the whole screen and i now have 3 giant buttons that have devided the screen into 3 rows. How can i change that to be at the middle with the hitboxes of the buttons being around them and not taking up the the whole row across? I tried changing some values at the `GridBagConstraints` but i think i have messed up.

Comment: @Kamora The buttons take up the whole screen because the default layout of the BackgroundPanel is the BorderLayout. I stated in my answer that: **you can easily change it to use the GridBagLayout.**. If you don't know how to do this, the tutorial demonstrates how to use a GridBagLayout. Please don't only concentrate on the posted code *I tried changing some values at the GridBagConstraints" - it makes now sense to try to apply GridBagConstraints to a panel using the BorderLayout. Any posted code is untested and is posted as a guideline. Take the time to understand the context of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the method `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and `drawImage()` from JPanel to draw your Image.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
public class AutoScale extends JFrame{
    
private Image image;

    public AutoScale() {
        setTitle("AutoScale");
        setResizable(true);
        setSize(400,400);
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(new File("path to your file"));
        }catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Image not found");
                 }

        JPanel panelImg = new JPanel() {

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                g.drawImage(image, 30, 30, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, null);
                }
        };
        add(panelImg);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        AutoScale frame = new AutoScale();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
}
```

In this example, I create the Panel and `paintComponent()`. Inside that method, I invoke `drawImage()` with 6 parameters:

1. The Image
2. x Coordinate
3. y Coordinate
4. The width of the Frame divided by 2(you can play with the size of your image by adding, substracting or dividing the result of
   `getWidth()`)
5. The height of the Frame divided by 2(same as the width)
6. The imageObserver, which generally is set to `null`.

The `paintComponent()` method gets invoke automatically whenever the size of the Panel changes, so there's no need to use a WindowListener as I suggested earlier.

Note: I use a try-catch block because if it can't find the file, it will throw an Exception.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: *You would have to create a WindowListener that detects that the frame size has changed* - there is no need of a WindowListener. When you use the appropriate layout managers the panel will automatically be resized and the component will automatically be repainted.

Comment: What you say it really makes sense but i cant figure out how exactly to do that... Can you write a code when you have your computer and add it here so i can take a look and use it?

Comment: @Kamora *i cant figure out how exactly to do that* - what do you mean? Dis you search the forum for examples that use the `drawImage()` method? There are hundreds of examples. What did you not understand from the examples? In any case you have already been given a link to a working example.

Comment: camickr posted a nice & tidy solution which has code and it's really well explained. Anyhow, I'll try to do it with a WindowListener so you have more options to choose from and, hopefully, you will see how it can be done in that way. As one of my teachers always said, "there are many paths that lead to Rome". Although camickr's path seems to be the best one!!

Comment: Also can you tell me how to get the new width and height every time the scale of the frame changes, i mean when the user rescales it?

Comment: @Kamora I just updated my answer with code and clarification! Have a great day.

Comment: @Jerónimo Squartini I just launched my menu with the image drawn out and it lagging too much... The buttons response is really laggy... How can i fix that?

Comment: @Kamora Oh I think I know what might be happening. Try creating the Image object outside paintComponent, because every time paintComponent is invoke, it has to go look for that image again. If you created outside that method (the constructor for example) you just re-draw the image every time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219759/discussion-between-jeronimo-squartini-and-kamora).

Comment: @Kamora, I gave you working code as soon as the question was posted. Not only that, I corrected, the incorrect information posted here about about using a WindowListener. My advice was correct hours ago without any updates or modifications and you still accept this answer??? You didn't even take the time to thank me for my help even though Jero agreed I posted the proper solution. I won't make the mistake of helping again in the future.

Comment: @Kamora, When we answer a question we assume you have basic knowledge (not lack of knowledge) of how use use classes and methods. As a new developer, we assume you are not familiar with all the features of the API and therefore attempt to introduce you to additional features of the API. Once you are introduced to these new features it is your responsibility to learn about the features. An easy way to do this is to look for example code, which is why I made the suggestion to search the forum for examples. However, I also provided a link to a working example that did exactly what you wanted.

Comment: *you could have given some explainations to help me understand* - Understand what? 
Even Jero stated in a comment: *camickr posted a nice & tidy solution which has code and it's really well explained.* If there is something you don't understand about the suggestions or the examples, then it is your responsibility to ask a follow up question, not ignore the suggestion. We are not mind readers. We can't guess what you may or may not find confusing.

Comment: Maybe you have heard the expression - **Give somebody a fish they eat for a day. Teach somebody to fish they eat for life.** I choose to teach. Or maybe you have heard: **You can lead a horse to water, but you can't force it to drink**? I gave you a solution that would solve your problem in one line of code. All you had to do was download the class provided, create an instance of the class using your image and add the panel to the frame. I would have thought you would be curious how to write reusable code with this powerful feature to do many forms of custom painting.